# Fetching Data(Image) from Google unfortunately stopped?

Tags: android, authentication

Google Authentication problem, while it shows all the data which have image. The account without image app unfortunately stopped. I don't get it where is the problem. plus checking if url is empty makes the same error. I am following the Androidhive.info example for it.

Plus what is the different between login with google and signup with google in android?
I am learning Android on own,can anyone pointout where I have done mistake. 
Any Help is appreciated.

```
public class Social extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSignin);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);

    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);

    llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

}


private void signIn() {

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}


private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            //Toast.makeText(this, ""+personPhotoUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Social.this, tester.class);
            intent.putExtra("User", personName);
            intent.putExtra("Email", email);
            intent.putExtra("Pic", personPhotoUrl);

            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception ep){

        }

    }


    else {
        startActivity(new Intent(Social.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
//          updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btnSignin:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btnSignOut:
            signOut();
            break;

        //default:break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
   // Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}


private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show stacktrace..

Comment: print  'result' is Logs to see which data is received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: null pointer exception

Comment: in both case result is true!